# How to extract data from a sql datatable using c#

Tags: c#, sql, selenium

I'm working on some automatisms, and i need to extract data from a datatable that my boss gave me, this one:

[image]

as you see there, there are three columns the first called quatro, the second called tres and last one called actualizado, don't mind the third one for now, i have a code like this:

```
Gdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.codigo-postal.pt/");
IWebElement searchInput1 = Gdriver.FindElement(By.Id("cp4"));
searchInput1.SendKeys("4715");//4730
IWebElement searchInput2 = Gdriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("cp3"));
searchInput2.SendKeys("374");//324
searchInput2.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
```

so what i want is, insert the numbers from the columns quatro and tres into cp4 and cp3, respectively, while there are numbers.

If anyone helped me, would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(""))
    {
        string query = "SELECT column FROM Datatable ";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string coluna = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("column"));
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```